# Procedure to troubleshoot Oven F2 error code

Tags: oven

Sear Roebuck Model 911.95492301 returns an F2 error.  The bottom heating element was corroded and was replaced.

The website: https://maxappliancerepair.ca/whirlpool-oven-f2-error-code/ indicates:

> The first step that you need to take is learning what the error means.
> Each error code is associated with a different problem. In this case,
> the F2 error code indicates that the oven temperature is too high.
> Now, this does not necessarily mean that the temperature inside the
> oven really is too high. The oven control board (clock) is responsible
> for measuring the resistance of the sensor circuit. It does not
> measure the actual temperature inside the oven. So, if there is a
> fault with this part of the appliance, it can result in false
> readings.

The advertisement then indicates 4 failure modes.

1. Check Contacts
2. Control Board
3. Door Lock
4. Sensor And Sensor Harness

What is the most common failure mode OR what are the simplest (easiest) tests?

Comment: I would start with 1 & 3.  If the resistance of one of the sensors is bad, it would be interpretted incorrectly by the board

Comment: Look at the instructions on testing those 4 items and determine which one(s) seem easiest. Start there. We don't know what your skills are, so we can't tell you which is easiest for you.